# How prove this $y=\sec{x}$ is continuous

Tags: analysis

**Question:**

> **can you use this** $\varepsilon-N$or other methods to prove this well know
>
> $ f(x) = \sec{x} $ is  continuous on $(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2})$

I think we also use this inequality
$$\left|\sec{x}-\sec{y}\right|=\dfrac{|\cos{x}-\cos{y}|}{|\cos{x}\cos{y}|}\le\dfrac{|x-y|}{|\cos{x}\cos{y}|}$$

But $|\cos{x}\cos{y}|\in (0,1)$,so
$$\dfrac{1}{|\cos{x}\cos{y}|}\in(0,+\infty)$$
so
$$\dfrac{1}{|\cos{x}\cos{y}|}$$ is not bounded

so i can't use this methods to prove it.Thank you

Hello,@paul,what you meaning for $2$? can you explain?

Comment: Use the quotient rule for limits. How are you defining $\sec x$ at the exceptional points? It is not sensible to say a function is not continuous where it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. Note that $\cos x\cos y= \frac12(\cos(x-y)+\cos(x+y)).$
2. use the monotone of $\cos x$ in the small neighbourhood of $x$